# How to clear WebView content?

Tags: android

I have a `WebView` in my app with `wrap_content` width and height

Before I use `webview.loadData`, the width and height of the it was 0, after I load a page (or I use `webview.loadData`) , it'll display a web page.

My question is , how can I clear the webview to recover it back to the original state,  just as  before it `loadData`?

Comment: possible duplication, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939530/how-do-i-clear-previous-webviews-content-before-loading-the-next-webview/25452749#25452749

Answer (score 89):

I found this answer, pretty helpful: [How do I clear a WebView's content before loading a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632590/how-do-i-clear-a-webviews-content-before-loading-a-page)

It is for Cocoa, but basically just call:

```
webView.loadUrl("about:blank")
```

Comment: But, by using such approach, this seems to have behaviour, you need to press the back button twice (I think the extra is for blank page), in order to navigate webview previous content. There's a discussion http://stackoverflow.com/a/8939753/72437 but I don't find it works for me.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng i'm using webView.clearView(). I know, it's deprecated, but this only acceptable solution for me now

Answer (score 53):

The only complete solution is to check for SDK version.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
   webView.clearView();
} else {
   webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
```

Comment: this solution helped me byt with `webView.destroyDrawingCache();` now works fine on all versions. Without destroing drawing cache were old content blinks on 4.4.+ androids

Comment: WebView.clearView() is deprecated, use loadUrl('about:blank") instead
Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearView%28%29

Comment: As @HugoGresse suggests, use `webView.loadUrl("about:blank")` for all SDK versions. `webView.clearView()` often isn't working correctly if Javascript is running, even in SDK versions < 18.

Answer (score 10):

use following statement before loadData:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.open();document.close();");
```

Comment: the above script is god sent .... the about:blank and then going back getting screwed was really frustrating ...

Comment: Much better than about:blank as doesn't create history. Nice trick!

Answer (score 5):

WebView.clearView();

This will clear the view from the webview.

Comment: Warning : Deprecated. Use WebView.loadUrl("about:blank") to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

I used the clearView() method, however I'm now having issues that when I loadData() right after it, it doesn't seem to load the data.

Answer (score 1):

What about loadUrl("about:blank"), and then clearHistory()?

Comment: It was a suggestion for an answer. Confidence is not at 100%.