# How do I clear a WebView's content before loading a page?

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview

I have an embedded WebView in my Cocoa application in which I load an external web page. Each time the user clicks on a button, the view opens and shows the page.

The problem is that the second time the user opens the WebView, the previous page is still visible. Instead I'd like to show a blank/empty page (together with a progress indicator).

How can I clear a WebView before loading a new page?

The closest solution I could find was to call this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close()"];
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this... Load "about:blank"

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I think of this... Sometimes it's the simple things in life...

Comment: `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];`

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:nil
                     baseURL:nil];
```

Worked for me nice.

Comment: This method only exists in a `UIWebView` (Cocoa Touch/iOS), whereas the question asks about `WebView` (Cocoa/OS X).