# Where to insert webview code on Eclipse MainActivity.java?

Tags: android, html, eclipse, webview

**Hello,
Im trying to insert a piece of a code into my mainactivity so when the user of my webview app tries to open it without having internet connection an error page appears.**

**This:**

[image]

**instead of this:**

[image]

**The code i already have in my mainactivity is:**

```
package com.mutesoft.kokobeans;

import com.mutesoft.kokobeans.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class kokobeansActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**And the code i have seen on [Prevent WebView from displaying "web page not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552160/prevent-webview-from-displaying-web-page-not-available) and want to implement is this because i think it can solve my problem:**

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");
            }
        });
```

**But im working with eclipse just for a few days and i dont know where to insert this bit of code. Can someone please insert it and paste it complete like he should be and "highlight" with different color or so where you put it? Tired of many errors i cant fix.. :)**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: I think it's more that you're new in Java in general. In both snippets you have a `WebViewClient`. Just merge them and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

you can always try and test for connectivity on start and if the device is not connected load actual HTML code from your raw folder instead of from a file.

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return info.isConnected();
}
```

p.s. this requires permission

Comment: can you explain me the "requires permission"? im really new at this

Comment: you need, in the `Manifest.xml` file, to add the line `<uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`