# Android webview error - how to hide flipped logo?

Tags: android

In my webview If there is error android flipped logo is shown

[image]

How to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

I probably understand what that logo is. From this question StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625379/where-to-insert-webview-code-on-eclipse-mainactivity-java).

I guess that your webview does not cover the screen, but the complete page is a 404 error -"Webpage not available".

[I think you can find your solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284186/android-webview-custom-error-page?answertab=active#tab-top) for a custom 404 error.