# webview error while loading a page without internet

Tags: android, android-webview

I am New to android.. I coded and android app to view a webpage in webview..
If internet is not there it will loads a default activity.. Or it will loads the webpage.. But Also if browsing via webview, And internet goes and a reload works it loads the error activity.. But in between that short seconds the default no page found error similar to browser comes for a second.. What will i do.. Please help me out.. I am really stuck here...

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
    check = new CheckInterNetConnection(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = check.isConnectingToInternet();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 
 mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
   mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        String desc="Oops something went Wrong";
           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String desc, String failingUrl) {
            // Toast.makeText(AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity.this, "Oh no! " + desc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity.this, error.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                         finish(); 
           }
         });
   if(isInternetPresent)
   {

            mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mybuzzin.in/lite");
    }

 else{
        //no connection
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.show();  
}


}   

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("Exit!")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();    
    }   

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url){
        super.onPageFinished(webview, url);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
     }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show an own error html page from assets

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");

            }
        });
```

Otherwise you can create a custom webview and prevent loading that

try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623202/3020568

Comment: This code loads the errorpage from assests But still the Webpage not available page is shown for a second.. any way to hide that.??

Answer (score 0):

this is simply very easy

you can check internet conncection before requesting url

```
 final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) YourClass.this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {

 webView.loadUrl(url);  

}else{
startActivity(new Intent(This.class,other.class));
}
```

//required permissions

add these permissions to your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

for more help contect me at rajeshsaini890 at gmail

Comment: Hi Raj.. Still the error page is loading for a short seconds then only ut get redirected to the other activy..