# Internet connection exception fail

Tags: java, android, android-webview, internet-connection

Hi I try to change the normal "No internet connection" page from android browser to a costum error page within my webapp. While doing this I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552160/prevent-webview-from-displaying-web-page-not-available) and in the answer was a well solution for binding a error page into my activity.

The problem with this solution is that my Url `http://192.167.0.45/loc/index.php` wont become loaded and only after any seconds the file `myerrorpage.html` become showed . How can my url become loaded and the other url only in error case? It look like the second `mWebview.loadUrl` override the first...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_localy);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());     
    // Load google.com
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.167.0.45/loc/index.php");

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not able to load the url you gave, so it jumps to the onReceivedError method, which then displays `myerrorpage.html`. The reason it takes time is because it has to confirm it cannot make a connection to the host.

Comment: You are right, I dont change my ip after changing the wlanprovider :D