# Android WebView when no internet show custom html page or no internet message

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello I am using Android Studio and currently making WebView app for a website

How to check internet on load and instead of showing default error - 
webpage not available instead of that can I show some graphical image ?

**My Code**

Activity_fullscreen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.croogster.android.FullscreenActivity">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</FrameLayout>
```

FullscreenActivity.java

```
    public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl("https://croogster.com");
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

and my AndroidMainfest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.croogster.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent WebView from displaying "web page not available"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552160/prevent-webview-from-displaying-web-page-not-available)

Comment: Check internet connection if it's not available then set another HTML page from assets and simply display into your webview.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a WebViewClient on your WebView:

```
 MyWebViewClient mWebViewClient;
 WebView mWebView;
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
```

That WebViewClient should extend WebViewClient:

```
 class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{}
```

In this class you are able to override onReceivedError, which reports error's that occurred (one of them is when you don't have any connection (I think it is the errorCode -2):

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

    Log.d("error code", " " + String.valueOf(errorCode));

    if (errorCode == -2)                                                                //errorCode 2 -> Server or proxy hostname lookup failed (no connection)
    // show to the user whatever you want to show, for example, a local html page:
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/localhtmlpagenoconnection.html");
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: sorry, cant understand it. can you please explain me where to add these codes. or you can connect with teamviewer to my pc and show me how its done, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView Client.

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            webView
                    .loadData(
                            "<div>Please check your internet connection.</div>",
                            "text/html", "UTF-8");

        }

        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());

        }

    });
```

Comment: tried this but showing error, cant set webview client too
and on Override there is no onReceivedError statement in my android studio :(

Answer (score 0):

Call the Connectivity Manager's `isActiveNetworkMetered()` and that's it. Copy- paste the below code in your activity.

```
     ConnectivityManager cm =
           (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean isMetered = cm.isActiveNetworkMetered();


    if (isMetered==true){
        //Device has an active internet connection.
        //Do your stub here

    }
    else {
         //Device has no active internet connection.
        //Do your stub here
    }
```