# How do I clear previous WebView's content before loading the next WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

My scenario is initially I am loading a WebView and later on I am loading the same WebView with a different URL.

My problem is whenever I am loading the next URL I can see the previously loaded URL contents and then my currently loaded URL contents gets displayed.

I want to clear the contents whenever I am loading the different URL.

Say,

```
if (pos == 0) {
    mweb.clearCache(true);
    mweb.clearHistory();
    mweb.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}
else if (pos == 1) {
    mweb.clearCache(true);
    mweb.clearHistory();
    mweb.loadUrl("http://android.stackexchange.com/");
}
```

Both `clearCache()` and `clearHistory()` does not work for me.

Answer (score 51):

use `mweb.clearView();` before loading the new URL.

**Edit:**

clearView() was deprecated in API level 18. Use `WebView.loadUrl("about:blank")` to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript).

to solve the issue raised by @Liang:

To have a consistent back navigation, you can override "onPageFinished", and inside it check whether the url contains "about:blank" or not. if yes, use "webview.goBack()"

Comment: clearView() was deprecated in API level 18. Use WebView.loadUrl("about:blank") to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript).

Comment: `WebView.loadUrl("about:blank")` will add a blank page in `BackForwardList`, so it will go back to the blank page if using `WebView.goBack()`. Can I remove the blank page in `BackForwardList`?

Comment: Anyone find a quick solution for the issue @Liang brought up? about:blank works except it adds a blank page in the back history.

Comment: you can override "onPageFinished" and check whether the url contains "about:blank" or not. if yes, use "webview.goBack()"

Comment: Hi @afairplayer, I try to `override onPageFinished" and check whether the url contains "about:blank" or not. if yes, use "webview.goBack()` but it doesn't work. Most probably I misunderstand that statement. Do you have a minimal code to demonstrate the idea?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng i'm using webView.clearView(). I know, it's deprecated, but this only acceptable solution for me now

Comment: This worked for me. I added WebView.loadUrl("about:blank") in onDestroy() method and set same line in onBackPressed() & it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

I usually hide the webview before loading the new url, and then show it again when the loading progress has advanced a bit.

```
// url loading
mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mWebView.loadUrl(newUrl);

// show webview again
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        if (progress >= 10) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is actually quite a nice approach. haven't tested it, but It's nice to see another approach than loadData("about:blank") have a +1

Comment: different approach. Works!!

Answer (score 5):

I guess you can use `Webview.clearHistory()`. But remember so impotent to call this after WebView is loaded. For example the code:

```
webView.loadData(someUrl);
webView.clearHistory();
```

won't work because webView is not loaded. We have to clear it like:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                clearHistory();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thnx to StefanK comment found [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Onpbm7esvsM), You need to use the `clearHistory()` method right when the page finishes loading in the `WebViewClient` `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` method also in the `onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` method; as follows:

```
    myCoolWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // Notice Here.
            view.clearHistory();
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // And Here.
            view.clearHistory();
            super.onPageFinished(view,url);
        }
    });
```

Also you can check the `canGoBack()` and `copyBackForwardList()` for manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to set the layer type of webview as "software" can resolve the problem.
Perhaps the previous contents are caused by drawing cache.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with the HTML for a blank page and load that into the webview.  Or hide it until it is loaded.

Answer (score -5):

use following statement before loadData     [Kuldip Bairagi]

view.loadUrl("javascript:document.open();document.close();");