# Clear Data in Android Web view

Tags: android, webview

I'm new in android developing. My app have web view,that page contain bill number and phone number text fields for view some reports. When I login and touch back typed data in web view are already in there. Can I clear that data using android web view's some function? like `clearCache()`,I have tried, but not working.

This is my code.

```
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(20);
            WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            String url = "http://aaaaaaaa:121/live/faces/reports.xhtml";
            webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452749/8591661)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

```
settings.setSaveFormData(false);
```